# Spark 1.4 missing Kafka libraries

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to run a Python spark script that works perfectly in spark 1.3.1.
I have downloaded spark 1.4 and tried running the script but it keeps falling over saying

> Spark Streaming's Kafka libraries not found in class path. Try one
>   of the following.
>
> 1. Include the Kafka library and its dependencies with in the          spark-submit command as
>
>    ```
>    $ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka:1.4.0 ...
>    ```
> 2. Download the JAR of the artifact from Maven Central http://search.maven.org/, Group Id = org.apache.spark, Artifact Id = spark-streaming-kafka-assembly, Version = 1.4.0. Then, include the jar in the spark-submit command as
>
>    ```
>    $ bin/spark-submit --jars <spark-streaming-kafka-assembly.jar> ...
>    ```

I have explicitly referenced the jars in my submit command and added the jars as

```
/opt/spark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit --jars spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.0.jar,spark-core_2.10-1.4.0.jar,spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.4.0.jar,kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar,kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar,spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.4.0.jar /root/SparkPySQLNew.py
```

It also says it has added them when the application kicks off, why is it not finding them?

```
15/07/08 05:44:37 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.0.jar at http://192.168.134.138:49637/jars/spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.0.jar with timestamp 1436334277792
15/07/08 05:44:37 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/spark-core_2.10-1.4.0.jar at http://192.168.134.138:49637/jars/spark-core_2.10-1.4.0.jar with timestamp 1436334277919
15/07/08 05:44:38 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.4.0.jar at http://192.168.134.138:49637/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.4.0.jar with timestamp 1436334278295
15/07/08 05:44:38 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar at http://192.168.134.138:49637/jars/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar with timestamp 1436334278353
15/07/08 05:44:38 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar at http://192.168.134.138:49637/jars/kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar with timestamp 1436334278357
15/07/08 05:44:38 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.4.0.jar at http://192.168.134.138:49637/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.4.0.jar with timestamp 1436334278665
15/07/08 05:44:38 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.4.0-sources.jar at http://192.168.134.138:49637/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.4.0-sources.jar with timestamp 1436334278666
```

And I know I have added in loads of them, I started off with one and then just ended up adding them all in by the end.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the exact answer varies per version of spark, but based on [this HCC thread](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/38764/getting-error-while-submitting-spark-job.html), the following seemed to do the trick for someone else:

```
spark-submit --jars spark-assembly-1.5.2.2.3.4.7-4-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.7-4.jar,spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.1.jar
```

At first glance a difference is that it has 1 spark-streaming-kafka-assembly jar, while you are submitting two.